# Reading large shape file into R

Tags: r, dictionary, geospatial, ggmap, rgdal

I am trying to plot the UK LSOA boundaries (http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/products/census/spatial/2011/index.html)  using ggmap.

I run the script:

```
library(rgdal)

system.time(

 LSOA<-readOGR("LSOA_2011_EW_BFE_V2.shp", layer="LSOA_2011_EW_BFE_V2")  %>% 
 spTransform(CRS("+proj=longlat + datum=WGS84"))


 LSOAtab= fortify(GMSM,region="Lsoa11cd")

)
```

the process takes 15 minutes and then will crash when trying to plot data on ggmap. Is there a faster way to read in the shape file? Perhaps by only reading in the set area I need to map at one time?

eg) the area given by:

```
library(ggmap)
maparea<-get_map("London",zoom=12,source="google",maptype="roadmap")
```

Comment: Can you switch to an other GIS (GRASS, QGIS)? Or simplify the shape?

Comment: Well I like the capabilities of R - specifically I am interested in making an interactive map using the Shiny package down the line. What do you mean by simplify the shape?

Comment: I mean: reduce the amount of data / details of the shapefile (do you need all details if want to plot it in a shiny app)